# Фильтрация объектов БД по нескольким значениям одного поля модели Django

Tags: python, django, фильтрация

Необходимо отфильтровать объекты из базы данных по следующему условию:
- поле `entryType` модели `Entry` должно содержать значение `'МРТ'` или `'МСКТ'`.

Пробую такие конструкции:

```
VK = Entry.objects.filter(entryType__icontains=['МРТ', 'МСКТ',])
VK = Entry.objects.filter(entryType__icontains='МРТ', 'МСКТ')
VK = Entry.objects.filter(entryType__icontains='МРТ', entryType__icontains='МСКТ')
```

- в первом случае пустой `QuerySet` `[]`,
- во втором случае - исключение,
- в последнем случае - исключение: `"duplicate keyword argument"`.

или так:

```
VK = Entry.objects.filter(entryType__icontains='МРТ') # результат соответствует запросу 
VK += Entry.objects.filter(entryType__icontains='МСКТ') # unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'QuerySet' and 'QuerySet'
```

Порекомендуйте, каким образом можно реализовать данное условие фильтрации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Q

entries = Entry.objects.filter(Q(entryType__icontains='МРТ') | Q(entryType__icontains='МСКТ'))
```